# Random без повторений числа

Tags: java, случайные-числа

Написал класс где генерируются случайные числа (без повторения значений) и записываются в массив.

```
public class MathBox {
    Random random = new Random();

    public int[] randomArray() {
        int[] array = new int[10];
        boolean numberAlreadyExists;
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length;) {
            numberAlreadyExists = false;
            int newRandomValue = random.nextInt(100);
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (array[j] == newRandomValue) {
                    numberAlreadyExists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!numberAlreadyExists) {
                array[i] = newRandomValue;
                i++;
            }
        }
       return array;
    }

}
```

Вывожу его в Main, но почему то выходит пусто, не могу понять, либо мозг уже не соображает в 4 часу ночи.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MathBox mathBox = new MathBox();
        mathBox.randomArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: "Вывожу его в Main...". Где? Где сам вывод-то?

Comment: чтобы не проверять все сгенерированные числа на каждом шаге (квадратичный алгоритм), можно использовать reservoir sampling алгоритм (линейный). [Пример реализации на Питоне](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35671225/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо `mathBox.randomArray();` можно вывести так `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(math.randomArray()));`

А то Вы вычисляете, но никак не выводите.

И почему нулевой элемент не участвует? Так задумано?

Comment: Точно.Большое спасибо!

Comment: Это ошибка, которую заметил сегодня, сонный мозг плохо соображал)